# Travel to Spain full vaccinated with a Russian vaccine

Tags: spain, russia, vaccinations

How can travelers full vaccinated with a Russian vaccine travel to Spain?

I see all the public information about that (https://spth.gob.es/info-pcr). That travelers should write a request to the Spanish embassy. How can I write this if the reason is a touristic visit?

Comment: I believe you'll need to have two EMA-approved doses before visiting any EU country, but have you contacted your local Spanish embassy?

Comment: @gidds I edited question, now this is more precise

Comment: Now we have two mutually exclusive answers (only one dose is needed vs. two doses), both upvoted. Could everyone please stop upvoting answers without actually checking whether they are correct? Upvoting incorrect answers is a disservice to the site.

Comment: "I see all public information about that" - Can you show links to the information you have already found? Make an edit to your post with what else you have already found to help get good answers

Comment: I put link that @NicolasFormichella post

Answer (score 11):

For Spanish authorities, non-WHO vaccines do not confer "vaccinated" status.

BUT, if you have the complete series of Sputnik-V (which IIRC are two doses), then you will only need one dose of a WHO vaccine (which include all of the EMA vaccines). The *EU Digital COVID Certificate* (DCC) will show that you have 1/1 doses of the EMA/WHO vaccine (you could also get one of those if you had been infected with COVID, since then only a single dose is administered as part of the regular prescription).

Be aware that the acceptance of vaccines that are recognized by the WHO but not the EMA (e.g. CoronaVac) may vary from EU country to country. We had issues with people who got the DCC at Spain but then had trouble in Italy because they only did recognize (at that time) EMA vaccines.

Source: I work as a programmer at a public healthcare organization and I have been tasked with the program that issues our DCC.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment I posted, you'll need to get two doses of EMA-approved or WHO-approved vaccine (or, if you lack your booster, get at least the booster as an EMA/WHO-approved vaccine) as stated by the official travel [site](https://spth.gob.es/info-pcr)

Sputnik V is in neither [WHO's list](https://extranet.who.int/pqweb/sites/default/files/documents/Status_COVID_VAX_18February2022.pdf) (read the *Status of assessment* column for the list) nor [EMA's list](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/human-regulatory/overview/public-health-threats/coronavirus-disease-covid-19/treatments-vaccines/vaccines-covid-19/covid-19-vaccines-authorised#authorised-covid-19-vaccines-section) so you are actually considered unvaccinated in most EU countries

Exception can happen, but for touristic reasons they'll basically never happen

Comment: The website also mentions WHO-approved vaccines, what about that?

Comment: Sputnik V is not in the WHO's [Emergency Use List](https://extranet.who.int/pqweb/sites/default/files/documents/Status_COVID_VAX_18February2022.pdf) either @Relaxed

Comment: That's useful to know, that might be the source of the OP's confusion. I found it earlier but I am still not sure I fully understand this table but does that also mean Sinovac and Sinopharm vaccines are WHO-approved? That's another distinction that could be useful for other readers. Either way, on the face of it, the website your citing doesn't exactly support your conclusion. The point of my comment is that you could add all this to your answer.

Comment: Sinovac/Sinopharm are indeed WHO-approved vaccines